# Determine the number of ways to arrange $14$ red and $5$ blue stones on a $1 \times 19$ board?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You're given a $1 \times 19$ board, with 19 boxes, I want to place $14$ red stones and $5$ blue stones. Given that you have a limitless supply of red and blue stones, how many different possibilities are there for such an arrangement of $14$ red and $5$ blue stones?

This looks like a combination with repetition problem, so I derived the equation $14r + 5b=19$ to help me use the equation $k+n-1 \choose k$ equation. The problem is that in all the cases I've seen, the equation always has a coefficient of $1$ - such as $x+y+z = 10$. In that case its simply $3+10-1 \choose 3$. But I'm not sure how I can apply this to my problem. Essentially I'm not sure if I should consider the coefficients of r and b or not. And if I do have to take them into account, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted the question as the following.

Given $19$ bins, in how many ways can we place $1$ ball per bin, so that there are exactly $14$ red balls and $5$ blue balls.

This is simply $$\binom{19}{14}$$